# Validating email addresses using jQuery and regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, email, email-validation

I'm not too sure how to do this.  I need to validate email addresses using regex with something like this:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)
```

Then I need to run this in a jQuery function like this:

```
$j("#fld_emailaddress").live('change',function() { 
var emailaddress = $j("#fld_emailaddress").val();

// validation here? 

if(emailaddress){}

// end validation

$j.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
         url: "../ff-admin/ff-register/ff-user-check.php",  
        data: "fld_emailaddress="+ emailaddress,  
        success: function(msg)
        { 
            if(msg == 'OK') { 
            $j("#fld_username").attr('disabled',false); 
            $j("#fld_password").attr('disabled',false); 
            $j("#cmd_register_submit").attr('disabled',false); 
            $j("#fld_emailaddress").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
            $j("#fld_emailaddress").addClass("object_ok");
            $j('#email_ac').html('&nbsp;<img src="img/cool.png" align="absmiddle"> <font color="Green"> Your email <strong>'+ emailaddress+'</strong> is OK.</font>  ');
            } else {  
            $j("#fld_username").attr('disabled',true); 
            $j("#fld_password").attr('disabled',true); 
            $j("#cmd_register_submit").attr('disabled',true);  
            $j("#fld_emailaddress").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
            $j("#fld_emailaddress").addClass("object_error");
            $j('#email_ac').html(msg);
            }
        }
     });
});
```

Where does the validation go and what is the expression?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/15659649/292060

Answer (score 495, accepted):

## UPDATES

- http://so.lucafilosofi.com/jquery-validate-e-mail-address-regex/
- using new regex
- added support for [Address tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags) (+ sign)

---

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = /^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i;
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
}
```

---

```
if( !isValidEmailAddress( emailaddress ) ) { /* do stuff here */ }
```

- **NOTE:** [keep in mind that no 100% regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses) email check exists!

Comment: thanks aSeptik apart from "missing" the e from mailaddress works well yes know that no regex 100% exists, but can get "pretty" close

Comment: didn't validate that too deep, but it already gave me a false positive for asdf@adsf.com

Comment: @gcb: hi, if the regex didn't satisfy your needs you can change it, anyway i have tested it and it work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ADPaM/

Comment: a regex alone on clientside, does not know if there is a mailserver nor if the domain itself exists. it merly checks if the syntax of any email is valid or not. Its only to help the user writing the correct address. its not a validation.

Comment: @aSeptik Hey, I know this is a few years old, but there are some bits of data there that fail and shouldn't, and vice versa.

Comment: @aSeptik I have used your code in a recent control I wrote. Hope it is fine with you.. https://github.com/vpfaiz/EmailArea/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses
From this there are only two that don't validate (postbox@com, admin@mailserver1), and it catches all the invalid ones.
By far the best regEx I've seen so far ;)

Comment: That regex does not allow addresses like hel\\o@boy.es or any escaped forbidden ASCII char in local-part. Source: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3696, page 5. (Scroll down and the [page #]s are at the top right corner.) But I don't know of any web, that would accept even "\#{; this "@thing.com, which is (I think a correct address) accepted with this regex.

Comment: link to demo restored

Comment: If you had Compilation Error using regex,  use @@ instead of @ .

Comment: how can I regex not become 100% ?? emails do always have the same structure so how can it not be possible?

Comment: if you want to use this in Razor, in setting up pattern should replace @ with @("@") . Very cool

Answer (score 30):

This is my solution:

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);
    // alert( pattern.test(emailAddress) );
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

<strike>Found that RegExp over here: http://mdskinner.com/code/email-regex-and-validation-jquery</strike>

Comment: your point about the plus sign is valid, but your regex is less better then the one i'm using in my example. ps: i have updated my regex to support plus sign.

Comment: Most times you just want to validate that the user entered the email in the right format. To identify typos like "2" instead of "@". So I like this better than the original answer but aSeptik's answer is comprehensive and I up-voted that as well.

Comment: test@gmail..com it say's vaild - WRONG, change regular expression

Answer (score 14):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#emailid').focusout(function(){
    $('#emailid').filter(function(){
      var email = $('#emailid').val();
      var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
      if ( !emailReg.test( email ) ) {
        alert('Please enter valid email');
      } else {
        alert('Thank you for your valid email');
      }
    });
  });                 
});
```

Comment: actually this was helpful. The title says JQuery and this is the only answer so far that has a decent jquery example.

Comment: this validates abc.b.@yahoo.com

Answer (score 7):

Lolz this is much better

```
    function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/);
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
    };
```

Comment: I prefer your solution for mobile websites. The other one would bring my smartphone to melt ;) +1

Comment: syntax problem oin javascript

Comment: It will not validate äüõ etc letters!!

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend that you use [the jQuery plugin](https://github.com/comfirm/Verimail.js/blob/master/src/verimail.jquery.js) for [Verimail.js](https://github.com/comfirm/Verimail.js).

**Why?**

- IANA TLD validation
- Syntax validation (according to RFC 822)
- Spelling suggestion for the most common TLDs and email domains
- Deny temporary email account domains such as mailinator.com

**How?**

Include [verimail.jquery.js](https://github.com/comfirm/Verimail.js/blob/master/src/verimail.jquery.js) on your site and use the function:

```
$("input#email-address").verimail({
    messageElement: "p#status-message"
});
```

If you have a form and want to validate the email on submit, you can use the getVerimailStatus-function:

```
if($("input#email-address").getVerimailStatus() < 0){
    // Invalid email
}else{
    // Valid email
}
```

Comment: Verimail keeps validating on keyup, which means, as soon as you start typing, you get an error message. Generally great plugin, but this one is a deal breaker - I would prefer to validate only when triggered manually, i.e. before clicking the submit button or leaving the field.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
var result = pattern .test(str);
```

The regex is not allowed for:

```
abc@gmail..com
abc@gmail.com..
```

Allowed for:

```
abc.efg@gmail.com
abc@gmail.com.my
```

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/10-java-regular-expression-examples-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

We can also use regular expression (/^([\w.-]+)@([\w-]+)((.(\w){2,3})+)$/i) to validate email address format is correct or not.

```
var emailRegex = new RegExp(/^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$/i);
 var valid = emailRegex.test(emailAddress);
  if (!valid) {
    alert("Invalid e-mail address");
    return false;
  } else
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function

```
 var validateEmail = function (email) {

        var pattern = /^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i;


        if (pattern.test(email)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Native method:

```
$("#myform").validate({
 // options...
});

$.validator.methods.email = function( value, element ) {
  return this.optional( element ) || /[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}/.test( value );
}
```

Source: https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.methods/