# How do you match a regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm trying to match the email regex `\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b` with a string in Javascript. At the moment I'm using the code `email.match(/b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/)` but it doesn't match any email addresses. Do regex's need to be changed before they are used in Javascript?

Comment: TLDs are not limited to having 2-4 letters in them…

Comment: For that matter, [they aren't limited to latin script](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-20004429-93.html) either

Comment: Can you show us your actual code that's not working, not just the regex?  (BTW, using a regex to validate an email address is generally considered a bad idea, since it's actually [impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156430/regexp-recognition-of-email-address-hard))

Comment: @Flimzy - agreed. I just check for the existence of the "@" as a basic sanity check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533344/check-for-valid-email-before-running-remaining-javascript/6533395#6533395

Comment: I'm not sure about the first 'b'? Do you really want just email addresses starting with a 'b'?

Comment: @flori - \b is a word boundary, presumably he's typo'd in the match() expression

Comment: @Richard H: Okay, a bit confusing in the second example the \ is missing.

Answer (score 5):

Problems matching email addresses with regex aside:

You have to add the *case-insensitive modifier* since you are only matching uppercase characters. You also are missing the `\` in front of the `b` (which makes the expression match a `b` literally) and the `\b` at the end (thanks [@Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/tomalak-geretkal)) (even though it will "work" without it):

```
email.match(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i)
```

If you only want to know whether the expressions matches or not, you can use `.test`:

```
patter.test(email)
```

[More about regular expressions in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: And the `\b` at the end. I think the OP made a misunderstanding when adding delimiters.

Comment: [This](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) appears to be the source of the regex, and yes, it is supposed to be case-insensitive and have a `\b` at either end.  Excellent article.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a RFC 2822 compliant RegEx for validating emails, even if it's a big one;

```
function check_mail(str){
    var reg=new RegExp(/(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/i)

  if(str.match(reg)){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

For more details on validating email using RegExs see [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Comment: No No I humbly disagree. There are real addresses that _don't_ comply with the RFC. Plus you've no idea if a valid format is a real email anyway, so what's the point. Far easier and more maintainable just to check for the "@" character as a basic sanity check.

Comment: Indeed, it all depends on what you are looking for: Testing a real email implies sending a mail to the adress. Testing a format can be limited to the "@" if you need a really quick test. I use my solution as an average one.