# How to validate email address containing non-english (UTF-8) character in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Lets say i have fallowing email address-

```
闪闪发光@闪闪发光.com
```

how i can validate this email...so that user can not enter this type of email address.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var email="闪闪发光@闪闪发光.com"
var match=email.match(/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/gi)
if(match)
{
    alert("correct");
}else
{
    alert("incorrect");    
}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/JXJ5q/

Comment: @Evert can you please give an example?

Answer (score 2):

Don't validate email addresses.. The best way to go about it is to simply look for an '@' and no spaces, and then on your server validate by doing a domainname lookup.

Comment: yes i have done that too...just wanted to validate this thing at client side too.

Answer (score 1):

A standard regex should be able to help, as it will disallow any characters other than the ones you specify.  May want to take a look at:
[JQuery validate e-mail address regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855865/jquery-validate-e-mail-address-regex)

Comment: Regex only works if you go for very simple checking. A full verification that can catch all valid and invalid will take many pages of regex due to all the exceptions, unicode and more.