# Swap default field value using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written some code in jQuery for removing/replacing the default value of an e-mail field on focus and blur events. Its' working fine,

But I wanted it in JavaScript .. I've tried several times but I couldn't succeed.

here's my jQuery Code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var email = 'Enter E-Mail Address....';
    $('input[type="email"]').attr('value',email).focus(function(){
        if($(this).val()==email){
            $(this).attr('value','');
        }
    }).blur(function(){
        if($(this).val()==''){
            $(this).attr('value',email);
        }
    }); 
});
```

can anyone tell me how to do it in JavaScript,

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: Before I edited it, your title had _absolutely nothing_ to do with your code. "Validation" makes sure something follows a certain format. Your code simply removes/replaces the default field value on focus/blur events, which is very different from _validation_.

Comment: Can we have an accepted answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `<input type='text' id="email_field"/>`

```
var email = 'Enter E-Mail Address....';
var emailField = document.getElementById("email_field");
emailField.onfocus = function(){
  removeDefaultText(this);
}
emailField.onblur = function(){
  setDefaultText(this);
}

function removeDefaultText(element){
  var defaultValue = 'Enter E-Mail Address....';
  if(element.value == defaultValue){
    element.value = "";
  }
}

function setDefaultText(element){
  var defaultValue = 'Enter E-Mail Address....';
  if(element.value == ''){
    element.value = defaultValue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
function validEmail(e) {
    var filter = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
    return String(e).search (filter) != -1;
}
```

with jQuery

```
var userinputmail= $(this).val();
var pattern = /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i

if(!pattern.test(userinputmail))
{
  alert('not a valid e-mail ');
}​
```

You can also try the following regex for other validation (I think this will helpful)

1. Matching a Username =>  `/^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/`
2. Matching a Password => `/^[a-z0-9_-]{6,18}$/`
3. Matching a URL => `/^[a-z0-9_-]{6,18}$/`

Comment: yeah great ... but as I've done in jQuery when I click on that e-mail field the default message gets disappeared ..  how to that part in javascript ... I used focus() for that but It didn't work ... 
Any idea ??

Comment: Look at the jQuery code in the OP's question.  It's not validating a email address.  It's automatically adding/removing the default value... that's what he's really asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you're trying to display a placeholder value, when there is no other value.

In any modern browser, you might simply use this:

```
<input type="text" class="email" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address..." />
```

Unfortunately that excludes older IEs, so an approach for vanilla JavaScript could be like this:

```
// grab all input[type="email"] elements
var emailFields = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT').filter(function(input) {
  return input.type === 'email';
});

var placeholder = 'Enter your E-Mail Address...';
// watch onfocus and onblur on each of them
emailFields.forEach(function(input) {
  input.onfocus = function() {
    // clear only if the value is our placeholder
    if (input.value === placeholder) {
      input.value = '';
    }
  }

  input.onblur = function() {
    // set the value back to the placeholder, if it's empty
    if (input.value === '') {
      input.value = placeholder;
    }
  }
});
```

Hope that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular old javascript for that:

```
function IsEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
```

======

- using new regex
- **demo** http://bit.ly/Hzbq4i
- added support for [Address tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags) (+ sign)

---

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

---

```
if( !isValidEmailAddress( emailaddress ) ) { /* do stuff here */ }
```

> - **NOTE:** [keep in mind that no 100% regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)
>     email check exists!

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855865/jquery-validate-e-mail-address-regex)

Comment: yeah great ... but as I've done in jQuery when I click on that e-mail field the default message gets disappeared .. how to that part in javascript ... I used focus() for that but It didn't work ... Any idea ??

Comment: can u show a jsfiddle.net such that i can see what the problem is

Comment: Look at the jQuery code in the OP's question.  It's not validating a email address.  It's automatically adding/removing the default value... that's what he's really asking about.