# email validation Syntax error

Tags: syntax-error, email-validation

I am trying to allow all possible characters for an email id during email validation and I am writing it this way-

```
^(\s)*[a-zA-Z_]{1}(a-zA-Z0-9.\-_`~!#$&amp;%^*()+,=:{}[\]|\\\&lt;>/?,.;'")*[@]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9.\-+_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}(\s)*$
```

But I'm getting a syntax error that says

[image: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list]
and the position it displays is after`;`

Am I missing something here?

here is the code that contains the pattern. This is being done during struts validation

```
<field property="email" depends="required,mask">
<arg0 key="alert.user.email" />
<var>
    <var-name>mask</var-name>
    <var-value>^(\s)*[a-zA-Z_]{1}(a-zA-Z0-9.\-_`~!#$&amp;%^*()+,=:{}[\]|\\\&lt;>/?,.'";)*[@]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9.\-+_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}(\s)*$</var-value>
</var>
</field>
```

Comment: Show us the pattern in context — the code that uses it.

Comment: @Matt: I've mentioned the pattern above the screenshot..

Comment: Why are there HTML entities (`&amp;`, `&lt;`) in the pattern? They definitely do not belong there. This might be a better pattern to use: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2855865/139010