# jQuery if valid show icon else show invalid icon

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to do the following, If one or more inputs have `"woocommerce-invalid"` class display error "red cross" icon else if all fields are completed display success "green tick".

I've tried with this, It added `"checkout-tick-one"` but would add/remove class if was valid or not.

```
$(".checkout-profile input").each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("woocommerce-invalid")) {
        $('.symbol').addClass('checkout-cross-one');
        $('.symbol').removeClass('checkout-tick-one');
    } else {
        $('.symbol').addClass('checkout-tick-one');
        $('.symbol').removeClass('checkout-cross-one');
    }
});
```

I need it to work with the following.

```
.on('blur change', '.input-text, select', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $this.closest('.form-row');
    var validated = true;

    if ($parent.is('.validate-required')) {
        if ($this.val() == '') {
            $parent.removeClass('woocommerce-validated').addClass('woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field');

            validated = false;
        }
    }

    if ($parent.is('.validate-email')) {
        if ($this.val()) {

            /* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855865/jquery-validate-e-mail-address-regex */
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);

            if (!pattern.test($this.val())) {
                $parent.removeClass('woocommerce-validated').addClass('woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-email');
                validated = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (validated) {
        $parent.removeClass('woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field').addClass('woocommerce-validated');
    }
})
```

So if one, two or three inputs had invlaid classes the symbol will show tick or cross depening if correct or not.

I also just tried, it seems to work but when i click on another field the icon changes even through another field has the invalid class.

```
.on('blur change', '.input-text, select', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $this.closest('.form-row');
    var validated = true;
    if ($parent.is('.validate-required')) {
        if ($this.val() == '') {
            $parent.removeClass('woocommerce-validated').addClass('woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field');
            $('.symbol').addClass('checkout-cross-one');
            $('.symbol').addClass('checkout-tick-one');
            validated = false;
        }
    }
    if ($parent.is('.validate-email')) {
        if ($this.val()) {
            /* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855865/jquery-validate-e-mail-address-regex */
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);

            if (!pattern.test($this.val())) {
                $parent.removeClass('woocommerce-validated').addClass('woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-email');
                $('.symbol').addClass('checkout-cross-one');
                $('.symbol').addClass('checkout-tick-one');
                validated = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (validated) {
        $parent.removeClass('woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field').addClass('woocommerce-validated');
        $('.symbol').addClass('checkout-tick-one');
        $('.symbol').removeClass('checkout-cross-one');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
if ($('input').hasClass('woocommerce-invalid')) {
    $('#someDiv').addClass('red-cross');
} else {
    $('#someDiv').addClass('green-tick');
}
```

**CSS**

```
.red-cross{
    background-image: url('red-cross.png');
}
.green-tick{
    background-image: url('green-tick.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** :

If input `hasClass` `woocommerce-invalid` then in if condition addClass to element for which you want to display red cross icon. But for that you need to add image in class which you adding.

```
if($('input').hasClass('woocommerce-invalid')) {
    // logic here
} else {
    // logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$('form')
   .removeClass('invalid')  // remove 'invalid' class from forms
   .filter(':has(.woocommerce-invalid)')  // find forms which have an element with class '.woocommerce-invalid'
   .addClass('invalid');  // add 'invalid' class to these forms
```

CSS

```
form { background:url(green-tick.png) 100% 50% no-repeat; }
form.invalid { background-image:url(red-cross.png); }
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Pp6wB/1/