# regex error - nothing to repeat in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I tried a regular expression to validate email id. When I use this expression:

```
var emailxP = /^(\w+([0-9-+.']\w+)*+\@+\w+\.([\\a-z]{2,3})(\.\w+))$/;
```

the expression is not working 
the chrome is showing

```
ncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(\w+([0-9-+.']\w+)*+\@+\w+\.([\\a-z]{2,3})(\.\w+))$/: Nothing to repeat
```

can please tell me what happen in there.

Thank you.

Comment: Try this one as a possible duplication here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855865/jquery-regex-validation-of-e-mail-address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*+` is invalid, you have to choose between  `+` and `*`

```
var emailxP = /^(\w+([0-9-+.']\w+)+\@+\w+\.([\\a-z]{2,3})(\.\w+))$/;
//                        here ___^
```

or

```
var emailxP = /^(\w+([0-9-+.']\w+)*\@+\w+\.([\\a-z]{2,3})(\.\w+))$/;
//                        here ___^
```

Also escape the dash

```
var emailxP = /^(\w+([0-9\-+.']\w+)*\@+\w+\.([\\a-z]{2,3})(\.\w+))$/;
//               here ___^
```

And why double escape for `a`?

```
var emailxP = /^(\w+([0-9\-+.']\w+)*\@+\w+\.([\\a-z]{2,3})(\.\w+))$/;
//                                    here ___^^
```

I propose this:

```
var emailxP = /^(\w[\w+.'-]*@\w+(\.[a-z]+)*)$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your regex inside `' '` and also escape the `'` inside your regex with `\`:

```
var emailxP = '/^(\w+([0-9-+.\']\w+)*+\@+\w+\.([\\a-z]{2,3})(\.\w+))$/';
// ------------------------- ^ here -------------------------------
```