# Validate email domain name using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to validate the entered email id domain using jQuery. For security reason we restrict the email id to only 2 email domain like **company1.com** and **company2.co, **.

So, if the user enters **user1@gmail.com** then we need to display the error message **enter a valid email address**.

The user is allowed to enter only like **user1@company1.com** or **user2@company2.com**.

I am using the below code but it is not working:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("domain", function(
            value, element) {
            var val = value.substring(value.indexOf('@')+1, value.length);
            return this.optional(element) || /'company1.com'/.test(val) || /'company2.com'/.test(val);              

    }, 'Enter a valid email address');
```

In rules I am adding **domain: true**

could you please tell me where I missed?

Answer (score 2):

The regex is wrong, you've added quotes and haven't escaped the period, which has special meaning in a regex, it should look like

```
/company1\.com/.test(val)
```

but it looks like there's an easier to way to do this without regex

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("domain", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || 
           ['company1.com','company2.com'].indexOf(value.split('@').pop()) != -1;
},'Enter a valid email address');
```

Comment: I used as per your suggestion. But if I enter user@company1.com, it also shows the error message

Comment: And you're sure something else isn't wrong? What happens if you remove `this.optional(element)` ?

Comment: If remove `this.optional(element)` same error showing.

Comment: I think this condition does not satisfy `['company1.com','company2.com'].indexOf(value.split('@').pop()) != -1`

Comment: Then I have no idea, it works perfectly fine for me -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/tcm4f9gd/**

Comment: I got it. I was using upper case `['COMPANY1.COM','COMPANY2.COM'].indexOf(value.split('@').pop()) != -1`. If I use small case `['company1.com','company2.com'].indexOf(value.split('@').pop()) != -1` it is working fine. Could you tell me how to use ignoreCase here?

Comment: Sure, `['company1.com','company2.com'].indexOf(value.split('@').pop().toLowerCase()) != -1`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regular expression:

emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@company1\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
and
 emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@company2.a-zA-Z0-9?)*$/

Answer (score 0):

> function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
>       var pattern = new RegExp(/([\w-.]+)@((?:[company1]+.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})/i);
>       return pattern.test(emailAddress); };

call function

```
isValidEmailAddress('user1@company1.com')
```

> if( !isValidEmailAddress( emailaddress ) ) { /* do stuff here */ }

chack this link [Validating email addresses using jQuery and regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855865/jquery-regex-validation-of-e-mail-address)