# .test for email filter work well on jquery 1.4.4 instead of on jquery 1.8.3 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, email-validation

This is my simple code for filter email on form submit;

```
var email_filter = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
if(email_filter.test($('#email').val()))
```

On jQuery version 1.4.4 this works well but on 1.8.3 the results change to;

```
say true on;  email@domain.e and email@domain.esse 
say false on; email@domain.es and email@dom etc..
```

Why does this fail on 1.8.3 if the code is the same, and how can I fix this?

Comment: did you check the value of `$('#email').val()` - the regex have nothing to do with jQuery version so the problem is somewhere else

Comment: I do want to mention that is a very bad regex for detecting a valid email. For example, there is a TLD called .museum so info@some.museum is a valid email address. Your regex says it's not. Additionally, with the gTLD expansion, I could buy a TLD called thisismytld so I could have test@something.thisismytld if I wanted to. The {2,4} is very limiting. It should probably be {2,}

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855865/jquery-regex-validation-of-e-mail-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think its jQuery problem,because your code seems to be pure javascript code except for the part to get the value of input field, and to make sure try using the following code:

```
function isEmailValid(value)
 {    
    is_email = value.match(/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i)!=null      
    return is_email;
}

// Test without jQuery
if( isEmailValid(document.getElementById("email").value) ){
   // Valid
}else{
   // Not Valid
}

// Test with jQuery
if( isEmailValid($("#email").val()) ){
   // Valid
}else{
   // Not Valid
}
```