# How to validate email and alterative email?

Tags: php, jquery

how to validate email and repeat email on same onchange in jquery?

```
<label class="labeln">Email Address: </label> 
<input type="email" required="" id="email" name="email" class="input1"> 
<label class="labeln">Repeat Email Address: </label> 
<input type="email" required="" id="remail" name="remail" class="input1">
```

Comment: You won't get a tutorial here. Please add more informations to your post and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to select input1 class because they have the same class
**HTML**

```
<label class="labeln">Email Address: </label> 
<input type="email" required="" id="email" name="email" class="input1"> 
<label class="labeln">Repeat Email Address: </label> 
<input type="email" required="" id="remail" name="remail" class="input1">
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.input1').on('change',function(){
  //Your validation here
  //But use $(this).val() to get the value of the email

   if( !isValidEmailAddress( $(this).val() ) ) { 
    /* do stuff here */ 

   }
});
```

[See this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855865/jquery-regex-validation-of-e-mail-address?answertab=active#tab-top) by aSeptik

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = /^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i;
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

[See also this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<label class="labeln">Email Address: </label> 
<input class="vEmail" type="email" required="" id="email" name="email"> 
<label class="labeln">Repeat Email Address: </label> 
<input class="vEmail" type="email" required="" id="remail" name="remail">
<script src="/js/jquery.validate.min.js'"></script>
<script src="/js/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

**Script**

```
$( ".vEmail" ).change(function() {
    //validate confirm email using jquery validate
    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            email: 'required',
            remail: {
                equalTo: '#email'
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Please enter email"
            },
            remail: {
                equalTo: "Confirm email is not match"
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you send the live URL

 src="/js/jquery.validate.min.js"
src="/js/additional-methods.min.js"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Validator - https://github.com/chriso/validator.js, the syntax is simple:

`validator.isEmail('foo@bar.com');`

It's a JavaScript library that I've used (and contributed to) extensively and includes custom logic for common free mail providers like Gmail and Yahoo. These providers have their own rules, and Validator accounts for that stuff too.

A simple regex (as other answers have suggested) is ok, but email syntax is actually pretty complicated, so better to just use something more sophisticated.

You can also use an [email verification API like Kickbox](https://kickbox.com) (disclaimer - I work there, we're awesome) if you want to be sure the email address is real and can accept incoming emails.