# What is Jquery's equivalent of php's FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validate email address in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)
>   [JQuery email validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507030/jquery-email-validation)

I would like to use filter_Validate_email to validate email.val() instead of what is below.

```
var email = $("#email");
var emailReg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;


   if (!emailReg.test(email.val())) {
        email.addClass("error").focus();

    } else {

        email.removeClass("error");
    }
```

Comment: Almost every answer possible is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507030/jquery-email-validation

Comment: Email validation is tricky, best regex you can use: `/[^@]+@[^@]/`. That won't leave any valid email out.

Comment: [mpyw/FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL.js: JavaScript Email validation compatible with PHP's filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)](https://github.com/mpyw/FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL.js#readme)

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) simply safes a lot of work.