# How do I check if an email field is 1) empty and 2) contains a specific email address with jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, events

Not sure why my alerts aren't firing, but what I eventually would like to do is enable the submit button when this field is not empty and contains a specific email address, such as "@something.com"

First things first, I'm simply trying to check if the field is empty on the change event.

HTML

```
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="lauren@something.com">
```

JS

```
$("#email").change(function(){
    if (this.is(':empty')) {
        alert('empty');
    } else {
        alert('not empty');
    }
});
```

Comment: Open up your console, and you will see the `Object has no method "is"` error that you're getting from trying to call a jQuery method directly on the DOM node object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Email validation using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507030/email-validation-using-jquery)

Comment: To use jQuery methods, you need to use `$(this).is(...)`.

Comment: @Barmar - `$(this).is(':empty')` on an input is always true, as an input has no children.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#email").change(function(){
    var domain = this.value.indexOf('@') != -1? this.value.split('@').pop() : '';

    if (this.value.trim() == '') {
        alert('empty');
    }else if (this.value.trim() == 'bill@gates.com') {
        alert('Holy crap, it\'s Bill Gates');
    }else if (domain == 'gates.com') {
        alert('It\'s a radiator hose salesman ?');
    }else{
        alert('someone else');
    }
});
```