# How to validate email addresses in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to validate a textarea for email and also I want that same textarea to allow a number of emails. I need this for a refer a friend option.

HTML part:

```
<textarea class="span12" id="demo"></textarea>
```

Comment: what where is the rest? did you even try anything? html should be final part :P

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
function ValidateEmails() {  
  var emailList= $("#demo").val().split(',');
    for (i=0;i<emailList.length;i++)
    {
       var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
       return regex.test(emailList[i]);
    }
}
```

you will need to enter coma seperated emailids in your text area

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really two questions:
 1. How do I validate an email from an input field?
 2. How do I validate multiple emails from an input field?

For #1, I'd suggest using the tried and true jQuery Validation library instead of rolling your own email validator. Docs here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/email-method

After including the jQuery Validation library, you'd call it like this:

`$( "#demo" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: false,
      email: true
    }
  }
});`

Of course that'll only work for a single email address.

To answer #2, you'll have to split the value of the textarea by some delimiter (e.g. whitespace, commas, etc) and then validate each string separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
function validateEmail(field) {
    var regex=/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i;
    return (regex.test(field)) ? true : false;
}
function validateMultipleEmailsCommaSeparated(value) {
    var result = value.split(",");
    for(var i = 0;i < result.length;i++)
       if(!validateEmail(result[i])) 
           return false;
    return true;
}
```

This will help you...
with some of example...
bill.gates@microsoft.com,steve.jobs@apple.com

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to validate email addresses separated by comma (,).

There's a submit and reset button, a textarea for taking the mails, and function `validateform` to validate the emails in the textarea.

```
<html>
<head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script><html>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="input">

   <p class="label"><h2>*Email Address:</h2>           
    <textarea placeholder="Enter ur mails by separator (,) " cols="30" rows="10" id="email_val" name="mail"></textarea>
   </p>  
<p id="demo"></p>
   <p class="label"><input type="submit" onclick="ValidateForm()"></p>
    <p class="label"><input type="reset" onclick="history.go(0)"></p>

 </div>
 <script>

 function ValidateForm() {
                var emailList = $("#email_val").val().split(',');
                for (i = 0; i < emailList.length; i++)
                {
                    for (i = 0; i < emailList.length; i++) {
                       // var expr =/^(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$/;
                        var expr = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                        var result = expr.test(emailList[i]);
                        if (!result) {
                              document.getElementById("demo").style.color="red";
                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "sorry enter a valid email adrress";

                            return false;

                        }
                    }
                           document.getElementById("demo").style.color="blue";
                           if(emailList.length==1)
{                          
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Ur email address is successfully submitted";
                        return true;
 }    else{
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Ur "+emailList.length+" email addresses are successfully submitted";

} 

                    }



                }

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*

Comment: Can you add some explanation? Just providing code doesn't help someone learn.

Comment: see i have given with whole html code it doesnt requires any further explanation

Answer (score 0):

There is too much different code for email validation - just look around:

[Email validation using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507030/email-validation-using-jquery)

Also, it is a bad idea to make textarea with emails. You should watch for separator, spaces, etc... Better to make a simple input, add emails to script array and then display as removable buttons.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$.validator.addMethod('demo', function(value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) return true;

    var flag = true;
    var addresses = value.replace(/\s/g,'').split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
        flag = /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i.test(addresses[i]);
    }
    return flag;
}, '');
```