# validate email without allowing spaces in jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I want to make email field without allowing spaces. I alread gave reg like the following

```
@"^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

Here how to add without spaces.. Help Me....

Comment: check here may be you get any help [Email validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507030/email-validation-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it in Jquery;

```
var email=('#myemailfield').val();//email field
var email_exp= /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/;

if (!email.match(email_exp)){ return Alert('Please, enter a valid E-mail to continue');}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this.......

```
var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/;  
var check = "Sunil";    
if (check.search(regexp) == -1)    
{ alert('invalid'); }     
else      
{ alert('valid'); }
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

User this regular expression this will help you.

/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@((a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9][2,4])+$/;