# Email address validation using expression

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-plugins

```
VAL.match(/^[^\\W][a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+([a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+)*\\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)
```

HI Friends, I am using above email address expression to validate email. Problem I am geting is it is not allow ‍‍‍‍‍‍`a@a.com` emai‍l adddress for testing.

Any one please quide me what need to be change in expression.

Thanks you

Comment: Relevant [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: Really, you should use a tokenizer and a state machine (or use a library that does it properly) if you're attempting to validate email addresses. They are *much* more complex than a simple regex can handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
/^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-+\s]+")|([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*)|("[\w-+\s]+")([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*))(@((?:[\w-+]+\.)*\w[\w-+]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][\d]\.|1[\d]{2}\.|[\d]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        };
```

check the value as

```
if (!isValidEmailAddress(getEmailID)) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this regexp

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/
```

see this link: [Email validation using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507030/email-validation-using-jquery)