# Setting a form to only allow .edu email addresses

Tags: javascript

I have a form that will ask users to enter their first and last name, and their school email. The script was set to only allow a @msu.edu email, but I want it to be able to take any email with a .edu email.

```
function send() {
        var regex = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@msu\.edu/i;
        var fname = $("#fname").val();
        var lname = $("#lname").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        if(fname != "" && lname != "") {
            if(regex.test(email)) {
                var newUser = new Parse.Object("StartupRegister");
                newUser.save({
                        fname: fname,
                        lname: lname,
                        email: email
                    },{
                        success: function(user) {
                            window.location = "msu_form.php";
                        }, error: function(user, error) {

                        }
                    });
            } else {
                alert("Not an MSU email.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("You must enter your name.");
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this? Why didn't it work for you? What was the result? What was the expected result? Where are you stuck in specific?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `msu` part of your regex to `(?:[\w]+\.)+` so it looks like:

```
var regex = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@(?:[\w-]+\.)+edu/i;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple algorithm that you can use :

1- you can create simple function to check if the email address is valid or not

2- match the email address from the end against the string **".edu"**

*real world example :*

```
function validateEmail(email) {
  var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
  if( !emailReg.test( email ) ) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

the previous function is from : [email-validation-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507030/email-validation-using-jquery)

```
function checkEdu(email){
    return (email.substr(-4) == '.edu');
}
```

the advantage here is that you have a validateEmail function that you can use in other projects

and the checkEdu function which is specific to this case

note :

substr(begin,length)  :  starts at the index begin and take length character

substr(-length)    :  starts from the end and take length character

Comment: That `validateEmail` function is wrong. For example, it says `postmaster@smithsonian.museum` is invalid.

Comment: Yes to solve this simple problem just replace {2,4} by {2,10 or any   other number that you want and it's okay}

Comment: That was just the tip of the iceberg of what’s wrong with it. The next minimal example of what’s wrong is that it rejects `john+doe@example.com`. Until you end up with [this regular expression](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html), it rejects valid email addresses and most likely accepts invalid ones. And even if you use that regular expression, the input needs preprocessing, because the syntax of email addresses is context-free, and fundamentally ***cannot*** be matched by a regular expression.

Comment: i agree with you the fact that we can't match all valid email address

Comment: Not with regular expressions, but there is a way you can match them. It’s just not going to involve regular expressions.

Comment: We can model this problem with DFA(Deterministic finite automate)

Comment: No; the `comment` production described on the top of page 11 of RFC 822 cannot be expressed with a DFA.