# Email validation using bootstrap & Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to validate email id using bootstrap I tried many ways but it is not  validating.

```
<label class=".col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-lg-8"  style="margin-left:-1%; margin-right:10%">Email</label>
<input name="Email" class="for" id="email" placeholder="EMail ID" required/>
```

Comment: I need bootstrap response

Comment: bootstrap validation? it is not making any sense, bootstrap doesn't provide any validation api on elements

Comment: Bootstrap for responsive textbox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Email validation using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507030/email-validation-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
<label class=".col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-lg-8"  style="margin-left:-1%; margin-right:10%">Email</label>
<input name="Email" class="for" id="email" placeholder="EMail ID" required onblur=ValidateEmail(this.value)/>
```

// in script section

```
function ValidateEmail(mail)   
{  
  if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(mail))  
  {  
    return (true)  
  } else {
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")  
    return (false)  
 }
}
```

Comment: Apostrophes (') are valid in the name part as are many other "special" characters.