# How to make jQuery domain validation for email?

Tags: javascript, jquery, email-validation

I have an input for email and have validation for a@a but not have validation for .com.nz , .com, .org .sg

How to validate domain in email using jquery?

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" maxlength="100" name="username" required="required">
```

Comment: [Discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507030/email-validation-using-jquery) Here is the link where it was already discussed.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom validation rule

```
$.validator.addMethod("customemail", 
    function(value, element) {
        return /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(value);
    }, 
    "Sorry, I've enabled very strict email validation"
);
```